# How to launch kubernetes cluster using vagrant?

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, cluster-computing

I am using Vagrant to a build Kubernetes cluster with one master and two nodes. Every time I run `kubectl get nodes` after switching my computer off and on again, I get the following error message:

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")

Comment: Could you please provide the github link for your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you did setup the kubernetes cluster. 
If you want to use vagrant you can use the setup [here](https://github.com/ecomm-integration-ballerina/kubernetes-cluster). This sets up one masternode and two slaves nodes.

Once the `vagrant up`command is complete, do `vagrant ssh k8s-head` and do `kubectl get nodes`.

You will get the list of slaves nodes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thats what I did exactly, $vagrant up, $vagrant ssh master, $kubectl get nodes.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to enter that command:

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```

its working for me.